# Cannot Detect Available Devices

Tags: angular, zxing

I'm using a tablet and my code does not get the available camera devices.

```
this.scanner.camerasFound.subscribe((devices: MediaDeviceInfo[]) => {
      this.hasDevices = true;
      this.availableDevices = devices;
});
```

this.availableDevices variable has no value after putting that lines of code on ngOnInit

html

```
<zxing-scanner #scanner start="true" [(device)]="currentDevice"></zxing-scanner>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like from [here](https://github.com/zxing-js/ngx-scanner/wiki/Advanced-Usage)

```
<zxing-scanner
    [enable]="scannerEnabled"
    [(device)]="desiredDevice"
    [torch]="torch"
    (torchCompatible)="onTorchCompatible($event)"
    (camerasFound)="camerasFoundHandler($event)"
    (camerasNotFound)="camerasNotFoundHandler($event)"
    (scanSuccess)="scanSuccessHandler($event)"
    (scanError)="scanErrorHandler($event)"
    (scanFailure)="scanFailureHandler($event)"
    (scanComplete)="scanCompleteHandler($event)"
></zxing-scanner>
```

camerasFound        Emits an array of video-devices after view was initialized.

so from [here](https://github.com/zxing-js/ngx-scanner/blob/6f8d3954ea39a3adbc17f0f5f02c6bdbff95416d/projects/zxing-scanner-demo/src/app/app.component.ts)

```
  camerasFoundHandler(devices: MediaDeviceInfo[]): void {
    this.availableDevices = devices;
    this.hasDevices = Boolean(devices && devices.length);
  }
```

Comment: Is the function `onCamerasFound` suppose to be called on `(camerasFound)` of <zxing-scanner>?

Comment: I updated the answer because the handlers had different names.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my problem using this..

```
this.availableDevices = devices;
this.hasDevices = Boolean(devices && devices.length);

if (this.availableDevices.length > 0)
 this.currentDevice = this.availableDevices[0];
```